# Remove viewpager item without reloading other items

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I used FragmentPagerAdapter.When I remove item from itemList and notifyDataSetChanged.Fragments reloading.In this case I am loosing datas in other fragments.How to achieve this without loosing data in other fragments

```
public class BasicViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragments;

public BasicViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.mFragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return mFragments.get(i);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}


public void remove(int cashBoxPosition) {
    mFragments.remove(cashBoxPosition);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

fragmentList.remove(event.getCashBoxPosition());
mAdapterViewPager.remove(event.getCashBoxPosition());

Answer (score 0):

save and restore the state via `onSaveInstanceState/onViewStateRestored` in your fragments where you want to save data, it's the only way to do it

Comment: now I am using viewpager 2.But it removes last item not my selected :).You know how to fix?

Comment: did try to call `notifyItemChanged(position)` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: it doesnt help.App crashes.Should use notifyDataSetChanged after notifyItemChanged(position).If I use notifyDataSetChanged after that nothing happens.Again removing last item

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved using viewpager2

```
public class BasicViewPager2Adapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

private List<Fragment> mFragments;

public BasicViewPager2Adapter(FragmentActivity fa, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fa);
    this.mFragments = fragments;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int i) {
    return mFragments.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position).hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean containsItem(long itemId) {
    return super.containsItem(itemId);
}

public void remove(int cashBoxPosition) {
    mFragments.remove(cashBoxPosition);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}